# Pricing and Quota for Reserved Static Private IPs and Instance Groups

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am not able to find any documentation on the following.

Does GCP charge for reserved static private IP addresses?

Whats the quota for reserved static IP address for a projects?

Whats the quota limit for Instance groups per projects?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for Google](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Does GCP charge for reserved static private IP addresses?
S: Just for unused ones. https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#ipaddress

Q: Whats the quota for reserved static IP address for a projects?
A: If you mean Global IP, 8 but it can be increased.

Q: Whats the quota limit for Instance groups per projects?
A: Not sure but, I think there is no Instance groups limit.

Comment: thanks for the answer Isamail..I am talking about private IP address..Not the global one.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the answers chronologically:

1. There are no charges for reserved internal static IPs.
2. You can only reserve up to 200 static internal IP addresses per project by default. Here is the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address#restrictions).
3. Your project is limited by the regional and global quotas for instance group. See the [Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?_ga=2.53481583.-635454678.1536784649) page in the Google Cloud Platform Console for a comprehensive list of quotas that apply to your project.